# Why is are the result values are in 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, properties

I have this code and I am trying to calculate the area and circumference of the circle. I have tried debugging and I can see that the `radius` was passed but the `area` and `circumference` is not, it's always 0.

```
using System;

class Circle{
    double radius;
    double area;
    double circumference;

    public double Radius{set{radius = value;}}
    public double Area{set{area=value;}}
    public double Circumference{set{circumference=value;}}

    

    public Circle(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
        area=0;
        circumference=0;
    }

    void CalculateArea(){
        area=Math.PI*Math.Pow(radius,2);
    }   

    void CalculateCircumference(){
        circumference = 2*Math.PI*radius;
    }

    public void DisplayArea(){
        System.Console.WriteLine("Area is {0}",area);
    }

    public void DisplayCircumference(){
        System.Console.WriteLine("Circumference is {0}",circumference);
    }

    
}


class TestCircle{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter radius: ");
        double radius=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Circle theCircle = new Circle(radius);
        theCircle.DisplayArea();
        theCircle.DisplayCircumference();
    }
}
```

this is the output

```
Enter radius: 
3
Area is 0
Circumference is 0
```

Comment: You never call `CalculateArea` or `CalculateCircumference`.

Comment: Why are you able to set the `Area` or `Circumference` from the outside? The whole point is to calculate them from the radius so why can you set those properties?

Comment: @Ferruccio oh yeah where should i call it?

Comment: What's the point of having fields for storing area and circumference values? You can easily calculate both of them on demand based off the radius value. Just get rid of these two fields, and let the getters for Area and Circumference properties calculate and return the respective values. And with respect to this, you would then _not_ call CalculateArea and CalculateCircumference, and you would get rid of these two methods, as they will not serve any purpose anymore. (Also, declaring setter-only properties here in your code is a nice, albeit rather silly touch ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very strange design: *set only* `Radius` (once set I can't read it), editable (both `get` and `set`) `Area`: one
can easily assign `-1.0` to it...

Let's redesign it; we have `Circle` class with three properties only:

```
class Circle{
    // Radius, the man property we can
    //   - read it (get)
    //   - assign it, but let it be just once (so set is private) 
    public double Radius {get; private set;}
    // Area, which we can just read (get, no set)  
    public double Area => Math.PI * Radius * Radius;
    // Circumference, which we can just read (get, no set)
    public double Circumference => 2 * Math.PI * Radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
      Radius = radius;
    }

    public void DisplayArea(){
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Area is {Area}");
    }

    public void DisplayCircumference(){
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Circumference is {Circumference}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so cool and helpful, btw, whats the use of "$" on your console.writes?

Comment: @clownzxy: `$"..."` is a *string interpolation* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: how about the => thing what do you call it?

Comment: @clownzxy: `=>` is a syntactic sugar, `public double Area => Math.PI * Radius * Radius;` is equal to `public double Area { get { return Math.PI * Radius * Radius; } }`